# How to add a link to route to another page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view page which i need to add a link to redirect the user to a booking page. I'm not so familiar with PHP so any guides would be helpful.

```
  <td>
  @if ($place->status==0)
    <span> Available </span>
  @endif
  @if ($place->status==-1)
    <span> Not Available </span>
  @endif
  @if ($place->status==2)
    <span> Booked </span>
  @endif
 </td>
```

This is the table i have, and i need to add a link next to the  of Available to redirect to another page called "quickbookingmodal.blade.php". This file is basically a pop up menu to add bookings into the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi. You can do this :**

```
@if ($place->status==0)
   <a href="{{ route ('quickbookingmodal')}}">Available</a>
@endif
```

**In your file route :**

```
Route::get('/quickbookingmodal','bookingController@index')->name('quickbookingmodal')
```

**Make sure you got an bookingController with :**

```
function index() {
    return view ('/quickbookingmodal')
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two options one is to add url link and another named route.Suppose you have below route registered in `web.php`

```
Route::get("status-available",[Controller::class,'method'])->name('statusAvailable')
```

Then

```
@if ($place->status==0)
    <span><a href="{{url('status-available')}}" >Available<a/> </span>
  @endif
```

or  using named route

```
 @if ($place->status==0)
        <span><a href="{{route('statusAvailable')}}" >Available<a/> </span>
      @endif
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: I see, sorry for the dumb question, but what should the value of the "urllink" be? or is just a name

Comment: any name you want to give.its just an example here as urllink